# Updating a value in JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I am trying to update quantity and price in cart.json.

```
addProduct(id) {
    // Fetch the previous cart
    fs.readFile(p, (err, fileContent) => {
      let cart = [];
      if (!err) {
        cart = JSON.parse(fileContent);
      }
      // Analyze the cart => Find existing product
      const existingProduct = cart.find((prod) => prod.id === id);
      const existingProductIndex = cart.findIndex((prod) => prod.id === id);
      if (existingProduct) {
        cart[existingProductIndex].quantity = (parseFloat(cart[existingProductIndex].quantity) + 1).toString();
        cart[existingProductIndex].price = (parseFloat(this.price) * parseFloat(cart[existingProductIndex].quantity)).toString();
      } else {
        // Add new product
        cart.push(this);
      }
      fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(cart, null, 2), (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

in cart.json file

```
[
  {
    "id": "ee195a4a-4870-4067-af50-c53c1d8f9594",
    "title": "Love",
    "imageUrl": "...",
    "price": "39.98",
    "description": "Love the way you lie",
    "quantity": "2"
  }
]
```

This is the code I wrote in cartModel.js and it working fine as I expected. But I don't think it's a good code.
Can you guys give me more beautiful code solution?

Comment: I personally think this's the only way the update content of a JSON file - read and re-write it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the way to add changes in the JSON file is a reading file, adding the changes, and writing a file. In your code, you can add some optimizations like this

```
addProduct(id) {
  // Fetch the previous cart
  fs.readFile(p, (err, fileContent) => {
    if (err) throw new Error(err.message);

    const cart = JSON.parse(fileContent);

    // Analyze the cart => Find existing product index
    const existingProductIndex = cart.findIndex((prod) => prod.id === id);

    if (existingProductIndex >= 0) {
      const existingProduct = cart[existingProductIndex];

      existingProduct.quantity = (
        parseFloat(existingProduct.quantity) + 1
      ).toString();

      existingProduct.price = (
        parseFloat(this.price) * parseFloat(existingProduct.quantity)
      ).toFixed(2);
    } else {
      // Add new product
      cart.push(this);
    }

    fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(cart, null, 2), (err) => {
      if (err) throw new Error(err.message);
    });
  });
}
```

You don't need to find a product twice. `findIndex` will return an index of the product if it exists (for example 0, 1, 34 ....), or -1 if it does not. Also, I suggest using the `toFixed` function, because the number can be like 12.123232523 so it will be shown as 12.12 if you are using `toFixed(2)`. Also, `toFixed` converting the number to a string, so you don't need to use `toString()` for the price.